# Redim Preserve. Вопрос сложней, чем вы думаете.

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Соответственно на C++ имеем класс:

```
  Class MyClass{ 
  public: 
        double *ptr; 
       void Set(); 
  }; 
  MyClass::Set(){ 
        ptr=new double[10000000]; 
  }
```

Далее в основном коде:

```
  MyClass *A; 
  A=new MyClass[10000];
```

Затем требуется изменить размерность массива A с сохранением его элементов, вопрос в том как это сделать максимально производительно !?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Способ в лоб: создать новый массив, скопировать туда элементы старого массива, уничтожить старый массив.

Правильный способ: использовать STL.

P.S. В таком классе, где происходит динамическое  выделение памяти, нужно позаботиться об уничтожении ее в деструкторе и о копировании ее в копирующем конструкторе и в операторе присвоения. Иначе дело может очень плохо закончиться (((

PPS. Вот тут на досуге накропал нечто. Приятного аппетита.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

enum  {SIZE = 10000, SIZE_CL = 5};

class MyClass {
  private:
    double* ptr;

    void array_cpy (MyClass& mc) {
        if (!flag) {            
            cout << "Copying array" << endl;
            ptr = new double [SIZE];
            memcpy (ptr, mc.ptr, SIZE*sizeof(double));                      
        }
        else {
            cout << "Copying ptr" << endl;
            ptr = mc.ptr;
            mc.ptr = 0;
        }
    }

  public:
    static bool flag ;
    static int count;

    void set() {
        cout << "Creating array" << endl;
        ptr = new double [SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i< SIZE; i++) {
            ptr[i] = count;
        }
        count++;    
    }

    double get(int index) {
        return ptr [index];
    }

    MyClass (): ptr(0) {}

    MyClass (MyClass& mc) {
        array_cpy(mc);
    }

    MyClass& operator= (MyClass& mc) {
        array_cpy(mc);
        return *this;
    }

    ~MyClass () {
        if (!flag && ptr) {
            cout << "Deleting array" << endl;
            delete[] ptr;           
        }
    }
};

bool     MyClass:: flag = false;
int MyClass:: count = 0;

int main() {
    MyClass* aa = new   MyClass [SIZE_CL];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_CL; i++) aa[i].set();
    MyClass::flag = true;
    MyClass* bb = new   MyClass [SIZE_CL*2] ;
    for (int i = 0; i< SIZE_CL; i++) {
        bb[i] = aa[i];
    }       
    MyClass::flag = false;
    cout << bb[3].get(400) << endl;
    delete[] bb;
}
```

А теперь с vector'ом:

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
        vector<MyClass*> vec;
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_CL; i++) {
            vec.push_back (new MyClass);
            vec[i]->set();
        }

        cout << vec[3]->get(400) << endl;

        for (int i = SIZE_CL; i < SIZE_CL*2; i++) {
            vec.push_back (new MyClass);
            vec[i]->set();
        }

        cout << vec[3]->get(400) << endl;
    }
```

Сравни выводы программы и проанализируй их. Я думаю, с вектором быстрее на порядок, потому что он работает с массивом указателей на объекты и это очень сильно убыстряет работу.

Comment: Вопрос как это сделать максимально быстро, ведь ptr в каждом экземпляре MyClass может ссылаться на очень большой обьём данных! Просто скопировать указатель ничего не даст, потому, что логично в деструкторе будет вызван delete[] который уничтожит выделенный блок памяти...

Comment: Можно ввести переменную-флаг, при поднятии которого в деструкторе и в разных там конструкторах копирования не будет уничтожаться или копироваться массив даблов. Ну, и сделать методы get-set для управления им. Короче, поднимаем флаг в исходных объектах, создаем новый массив, копируем, уничтожаем старый, опускаем флаг в новых экземплярах. Массивы даблов остались на месте и сохранились указатели на них.

Comment: Навели меня на мысль, а если не использовать флагов, а в методе копирования класса для блокирования деструктора (delete[] ptr) просто скопировать указатель newptr=ptr, а родному ptr присвоить NULL, корректно ли вызовется деструктор !?

Comment: Так ведь @mikillskegg написал: использовать STL (Степанов и Ли Библиотека). Вместо массива MyClass использовать vector. Там есть и std::vector<>::resize

Comment: А что использование в данном случае STL гарантирует производительность!?

Comment: @rejie, но ведь рано или поздно нужно будет уничтожить эти массивы и это должно быть гарантировано при уничтожении объектов. Иначе будет утечка памяти.

STL, боюсь, в данной ситуации скорость не гарантирует, зато гарантирует корректность процедуры.

Comment: @rejie а нельзя перевести вопрос? Что значит "гарантирует производительность"? Самые тормоза должны на этих операциях быть при выделении/уничтожении блоков по 80М без малого. Так это не зависит от vector.

Comment: Благодарю за мнение, но если позаботится о производительности, и уйти от стандартных решений!?

Comment: Так в том то идея, что зачем удалять и заново создавать, возникла идея с манипуляцией указателями!

Comment: Так я говорю, что перед delete[] надо проводить проверку flag в if.

if (flag == false) delete[] ptr;

Comment: Так я и повторяю, если ptr=NULL, корректен ли вызов delete [] ptr!& :)

Comment: Не знаю, как с обстоит дело с деструкторами в C++. 

На C для массива A (а Class MyClass это по сути дела массив double \*) я бы просто сделал realloc(). Все указатели на массивы double естественно сохранятся, просто могут переехать на другое место. 

Само собой при **уменьшении** размера A для "урезаемых" массивов double надо вызывать free().

Comment: @rejie, вызов корректен, ошибки не будет, но вот надо ли это делать? Будет потрачено время на вызов delete[]. Вы же дуемаете об эффективности? Кроме того, флаг можно сделать static, тогда можно будет его ставить и опускать для всех объектов сразу одним действием.

Comment: @avp, память под объекты нельзя выделять malloc(), только new. Иначе может куча неприятностей вылезти.

Comment: Дело, то не в указателях на массив, а в массиве! В С++ вопрос рассматривается в контексте взаимосвязанных классов! Вам отдельный респект за отличное знание C !

Comment: Про производительность: Vector containers are implemented as dynamic arrays; Just as regular arrays, vector containers have their elements stored in contiguous storage locations, which means that their elements can be accessed not only using iterators but also using offsets on regular pointers to elements. Для выделения с запасом там есть reserve. А вот про взаимосвязанные классы -- это уже интересней. Я что-то не понял, а кто уничтожает массив, на который указывает MyClass.ptr?

Comment: @mikillskegg, я написал, что для **Си, а не C++**. Вообще предпочитаю его т.к. он проще (прозрачнее, меньше подводных камней, просто плохо знаю плюсы ... и т.п.)

Comment: @avp, сейчас разговор за С++ и его причуды.

Comment: Для простых прямолинейных программ я тоже предпочитаю С.

Comment: Если мы делаем delete[] A, трудится деструктор

Comment: Склоняюсь к использованию флага...

Comment: @rejie, какие могут быть девушки, когда тут...  ДЕСТРУКТОРЫ!!!

Comment: Ну в примере, приведённом в вопросе, про деструктор не сказано ни слова. А деструктор по умолчанию, как я понимаю, не трудоголик. Да и вообще, при указанных цифрах (1000 против 10000000) всё это похоже на героическую попытку сэкономить на спичках. И ещё: "не много определился" -- это "немного", "несколько" или "ни фига"?

Comment: На счёт деструктора я не стал писать, но раз я порадил память то соответственно я её убил!

Comment: А что касается мегабайт памяти то это порядок 500-1000 мб!

Comment: Бедолага. Рядом девушки в чулочках, а он -- про деструкторы. Да Господь с ними, с деструкторами, своп-то здоровый, чего его жалеть...

Comment: Здоровый то здоровый, математических итераций слишком много, гонять туда сюда - ноу гуд!!! А Дамы отменные!

Comment: Ты сравниваешь совсем разные вещи: указатель на массив и динамический массив указателей. Надо сравнивать либо `MyClass*` и `vector<MyClass>`, либо `MyClass**` и `vector<MyClass*>`.

Comment: Да вижу, вижу, но он, сволочь, не хочет в вектор втыкаться. Вообще можно вывести мораль, что иногда удобнее оперировать не с контейнерами объектов, а с указателей на объекты.

Comment: А что значит "не хочет втыкаться"?

Comment: Если пишу vector<MyClass> vec, то g++ выдает кучу всякой хрени. Нет времени разбираться, в чем дело.

Comment: Разобрался, в чем дело. Нужно было в конструктор копирования и operator= делать параметр не MyArray&, а const MyArray&. Ну и, соответственно, в функции array_cpy кое-что поправить.

Comment: Если склоняться в сторону STL и есть необходимость всё это дело завернуть в DLL, которая должна возвращать результат, то каким образом это реализовать!? Как возвращать вектор!?

Answer (score 2):

Есть подход при котором большой массив храниться в виде дерева под-массивов.
Есть базовый массив (назовем его а) в нем хранятся указатели на массивы (bi) и длинна каждого из них. При запросе элемента х из данного массива сначала происходит обращение к массиву "а", в нем определяется в каком из массивов "b" находится данный элемент и забирает его от туда. Данный подход очень удобен при изменении размеров массива т.к. нам нужно просто выделить место под новый массив и добавить ссылку на него в массив.

Есть еще куча преимуществ из недостатков несколько более медленное обращение к элементу массива.

Если нужно подробнее и с картинками напиши в коментах.

Answer (score 2):

Я как-то соревновался с STL, пытаясь создать контейнер, который быстрее стандартного. Я написал класс, который пишет, когда вызывается его конструктор, конструктор копирования и деструктор. При реаллокации и удалении элементов из середины vector<MyClass> генерировал кучу сообщений. В своём массиве я сделал так, что конструктор вызывается только при добавлении элемента, а деструктор при удалении. Даже при перераспределении памяти элементы не копируются и не удаляются.

Вот как я этого добился. Я выделял память при помощи malloc и освобождал через free, которые работают с пустой памятью, а не с объектами. Конструкторы и деструкторы я вызывал вручную. При перераспределении памяти я использовал realloc. Не вызывается никаких конструкторов и деструкторов. Получается, что просто поменялся адрес объекта (а если realloc смог просто увеличить буфер, то и не поменялся!). По сравнению с вектором это вводит небольшое ограничение: нельзя хранить в контейнере объекты, которые полагаются на то, что их адрес всегда будет неизменным. В любом случае, такие объекты встречаются очень редко, а в векторе и так очень много более важных ограничений.

Этот подход можно применить и здесь:

```
struct MyClass
{
    double* ptr;

    //Ты забыл конструктор и деструктор
    MyClass() {Set();}
    ~MyClass() {Clear();}

    void Set() {ptr=new double[10000000];}
    void Clear() {delete[] ptr; ptr=nullptr;}
};
```

В основном коде:

```
MyClass* A=malloc(10000*sizeof(MyClass));

//Вызываем конструкторы
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
    new(A+i) MyClass;
//...
//Работаем с ним до того, как перестанет хватать места
//...
A=realloc(A, 20000*sizeof(MyClass));

//Вызываем конструкторы для новых 10000 объектов
for(int i=10000; i<20000; i++)
    new(A+i) MyClass;

//...
//Удаляем
for(int i=0; i<20000; i++)
    a[i].~MyClass();
free(A);
```

Здесь используется размещающий new. Если будет ошибка компиляции, возможно понадобится подключить файл new.h. MyClass просто играет роль какой-то нагрузки, и неважно, что он делает и как выделяет память.

Comment: Кто бы мне всё-таки объяснил, из-за чего буза? Размер этого самого A на 32бит компутере изначально 40кб. При том, что его элементы ссылаются на 10000 * 80млн. байт = 800 млрд. байт. И нужно это дело (40-80кб) оптимизировать. Нафига? По сравнению с общими затратами это такие мелочи... Ну ладно, на 32бит системы это не полезет -- адресов не хватит. Ну 80-160кб...

Comment: MyClass я из вопроса взял и немного подредактировал, просто добавив туда конструктор и деструктор. Про "10000 * 80млн. байт = 800 млрд. байт" спрашивай у автора вопроса.

>И нужно это дело (40-80кб) оптимизировать. Нафига? По сравнению с общими затратами это такие мелочи...

 Я уменьшаю количество вызовов конструктора и деструктора MyClass, а не оптимизирую 40-80 кб. Благодаря этому MyClass.ptr не надо копировать по многу раз при перераспределении.

Comment: Без @rejie сей великой мудрости всё равно не понять. Какой-то сферический конь в вакууме.

Comment: Сферический конь в вакууме? А разве это что-то непонятное?

Comment: Если склоняться в сторону STL и есть необходимость всё это дело завернуть в DLL, которая должна возвращать результат, то каким образом это реализовать!? Как возвращать вектор!?

Comment: >Если склоняться в сторону STL и есть необходимость всё это дело завернуть в DLL, которая должна возвращать результат, то каким образом это реализовать!? Как возвращать вектор!?

 А причём тут STL? В моём ответе нет использования STL. Он тебе не поможет, если, конечно, не хранить только указатели. Мой вариант лучше всего, так как требует меньше всего аллокаций памяти.

 Возвращать стандартные контейнеры из функций DLL не самая лучшая идея. Если DLL и программа собраны разными компиляторами или хотя бы с разными параметрами компиляции, то их размеры могут не совпасть.